# Webpack Source Maps

Tags: webpack, jhipster, webpack-dev-server

I recently started using [JHipster@4.0](https://jhipster.github.io) with the Angular2 template.  This is the first time I am using a webpack build, so I am still working on getting my feet under me with webpack.

One of the first things I noticed was in Chrome debugging tools, I no longer have the list of files that were compiled into the web artifact (as provided by the source maps).  Instead I just have a single file `main.bundle.js`.

Is there a way to have a similar layout with source maps, where I am easily able to navigate to a specific file I want to work with/debug?  (I may also be doing something wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Your source files should be visible in the webpack:// pseudo-path in the Sources tab of Chrome Devtools.

[image]

Comment: I only see `localhost:9000` and `(no domain)` under the top element on the sources page.  The `(no domain)` contains all of the `ngfactory.js` files.  Is there a Chrome plugin or something I am missing?

Comment: No special plugin, only Chrome devtools. In my screenshot you'll see app source files in 2 places: under webpack and under app.